# Need help searchfunction for my moviedatabase C++

Tags: c++, search-engine, linear-search

I'm having some trouble with my moviedatabase, my searchfunction isn't working.
I'm a total beginner and have gotten the searchfunction of the net, but it wont search.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> // För att kunna använda sig av getline()
#include <string> // För att kunna använda sig av getline()
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Film
{
public:
    string Titel;
    string Typ;

// FUNKTION: Skriver ut filmens titel och typ
    void skrivUtFilm()
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Titel: " << Titel << endl; // Skriver ut filmens titel
        cout << "Typ: " << Typ << endl; // Skriver ut filmens typ
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Film> Databas;             // Skapa en vektor av typen Film

    Film nyFilm;                    // För att kunna skapa en film behöver vi kunna spara den

    while (true)
    {
        // Skriver ut menyn:
        cout << " === FILMDATABAS === " << endl;
        cout << "1: Registera en ny film"   << endl;
        cout << "2: S\x94k efter en film"   << endl;
        cout << "3: Skriv ut filmlistan"    << endl;
        cout << "0: Avsluta"    << endl;
        cout << "Ange ditt val: ";

        char menySelection; // Användarens val
        cin >> menySelection;


        if (menySelection == '1') // Registerar nya filmer
        {
            cin.get();
            cout << "\n\n1: Registrera en ny film\n";
            cout << "Vad \x84r filmens Titel: ";
            getline(cin, nyFilm.Titel);

            cout << "\x8er filmen p\x86 DVD eller BluRay? ";
            getline(cin, nyFilm.Typ);
            cout << endl;

            // Vi lägger vårt filmobjekt i vektorn
            Databas.push_back( nyFilm );
        }
        else if (menySelection == '2') // Söker efter filmer som användaren har lagt till
        {
            cin.get();
            cout << "\nS\x94k efter filmer i databasen: \n\n";
            string objekt;
            getline(cin, objekt);
            cout << endl;

            vector<Film>::iterator it;

            it = find_if(Databas.begin(), Databas.end(),[&] ( const Film &f )
            {
                return ( f.Titel == objekt);
            });
        }
        else if (menySelection == '3') // Skrivet ut alla filmer i Filmarkivet
        {
            cout << "\n=========\n";
            cout << "Filmlistan\n";
            for(int i=0; i<Databas.size(); i++)
            {
                Databas[i].skrivUtFilm(); // Skriver ut dem med hjälp av skrivUtFilm();
            }
            cout << "\n=========\n";
            cout << "\n\nTryck p\x86 ENTER f\x94r att \x86terv\x84nda till menyn.\n\n";
            cin.get();
        }
        else if (menySelection == '0') // Avslutar programmet
        {
            break;
        }
        else   
        {
            cout << "Ogiltigt val!\n." << endl;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working?  You don't check the iterator returned from find_if so it may be working fine and you don't know it.  A linear search is just iterating through the vector and comparing against the title.  Not difficult.

Comment: The thing that isn't working is after I've registered a movie with option 1, I want to search for it in option 2, but when I've write either the type or the title and press enter, it just goes back to showing the menu again, without returning any information about the movie/type. I don't know if I'm using the wrong code for what I want to do.

Comment: Like I said, you're not doing anything with the data you get from your search.  You need to use the iterator that `find_if` returns in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find the film, you don't do anything with it.

After the search function, you should add something like:

```
if (it != Databas.end()) {
    it->skrivUtFilm();

} else {
    cout << "No film found" << endl;

}
```

to print info about the film that you have found, or a message that no film was found.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help LPCs, it works as intended now, I'm greatful that you took your time to help me :)